# What is the best method for storing and retrieving images on web server?

Tags: php, sql, image

I have a website that relies heavily on my sql database. I store product information in the database and retrieve and format it with php. I'd like to add images to the equation but don't know where to start. They are high resolution so I don't think storing them in the actual database is advised, but I don't want other administrators to spend hours inputting product information and images. As is stands, admins fill out forms, verify the information is correct, and the information is stored then displayed on the website. When it comes to images the best I could think of was adding the image name and location to the product information and calling it back with php but I don't want my admins to take all day to name photos and manually type the name in. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The *best* method may differ between people, however I suggest storing the exact image location in db. Then echo the location in an src.

Comment: You are correct - storing the images in the database, whilst possible, is not advised - especially when they are high-resolution. You could write a script quite easily that scans a directory and adds each image to the db. You could also present the admin with a visual image selector so they click on an image to add that image / path to the form

Comment: You say you don't want them to spend all day naming the photos, but how else could the images possibly get a name?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would advice storing the images in a durable and scalable storage facility like [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/), which removes a lot of the burdens for you and makes it possible to host the images through cost effective CDN at pretty much any scale (small or big).

You need not worry about a human manually naming the image files as they can be randomly assigned unique names through code. For example, you could use the md5 sum of the image file to uniquely identify images and only store their S3 bucket and object id in your database to retrieve them from the web easily even if you decide to later change some of the information.

Also, since you're stating that you'll be associating an image with a specific product in your database, there's probably no need to globally identify unique image data across the board. You could just limit it to the associated product and that might be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to do so is to save on a website,  say a bucket,  better a **CDN** [like AWS S3] rather that in your own server,  and store the URL path and name on your DataBase.  DataBases have the capability to store images, but I do not recommend it to you.

The workflow is to create a form where the image/s can be uploaded to the server,  then insert in your **item_images** table the name, extension and **URL**.

When retrieving the images,  say in a product catalog, just query the url from your database and use **PHP** to display to the user,  placing the url inside the **src** property of each **img** tag.

```
<img alt="" src="<?php echo img_url[];?>" width="" class="">
```

To consider:

1. Files like images need a particular **enctype**:

   ```
   <FORM id="" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   ```
2. Files are captured not by $_POST or $_GET, but by $_FILES array.
3. Clean uploaded files before storing on the server.  Avoid **.exe**, **.php** and many others.
4. Limit the size and mime type of images using **GETIMAGESIZE()**.
5. Use **MOVE_UPLOADED_FILE** to physically store the images on your server, because before that,  files are just temporary files.
6. For naming images,  better use a semantic web approach, and combine it with each item's id.

   ```
   $image_name=$item_category.$item_id.$extension
   ```

Comment: Saving the url into the database is the method I've chose for now. I was wondering if it's better to have multiple columns for each link or if there's a way to store them all in one and echo them individually?